# How safe are electric faucet water heater?

Tags: electrical, water-heater, faucet

I would like to buy one of those [electric faucet water heaters](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2016-New-LCD-Electric-Faucet-electric-water-heater-electric-hot-water-tap-Intelligent-Digital-Kitchen-Instant/32920597804.html) for my parents. 
 
But I'm very concerned about if they are even safe to use and some questions came into my mind:

- how is the internal wiring shielded from the water?
- how dangerous would it be if the cables which goes to the heating element get in contact with the water?
- why are they (as far as I know) only available in China and not at my local hardware store in Germany?
- (maybe off topic but is it even legal to install/use them, also regarding to insurance?)

Comment: There should be under-sink waterheaters available in you local plumbing supply store. A bit bulkier but you'll know that they are legal and safe.

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, I know about those but there is not enough space for those. And I though such a in-faucet-heater would be a nice solution

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You can get a broad range of qualities when buying direct from China, and there's no way that you (or we) could know whether these are truly safe. All we could say would be "don't know", "probably very", "no idea", "don't know".

Comment: Hello @DanielGriscom and thanks for welcoming me. Maybe I could reword my question to something like "how to check if the device is safe" after I purchased one. Do you think it would be a better fit?

Comment: That, too, would probably be off-topic here, as it isn't a "home improvement" but a "electrical safety testing" topic. Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider them unsafe for the U.S. market for 2 possibly 3 reasons. First it is not U.L. listed this means it has not passed normal testing for being used in the U.S. 
Next, it comes with a different style plug so the first thing you would do to use it is modify it electrically so you could use it.
Another item is it has metric plumbing, this may not be a big safety thing but you may have trouble adapting this to your parents plumbing. If a failure it may just leak or flood an area of the home.
With these issues I would check a plumbing store or big box store they may have something similar that probably will cost more but would be listed for use here thus be legal. I was thinking the country plugs this comes with are on a different standard than we are so I found the voltage is 220 so you will probably need that brought to the location as most outlets in North America are 120v.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My parents live in Germany, so 220V would be fine as well as the metric plumbing afaik. The most thing I'm concerned about are internal electric failures which could lead to electric shocks. A device with 3000W rating would draw a lot of voltage/ampere, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

#### Safety First!

Ed Beal raises a number of issues with this specific item, particularly U.L. (or similar) listing regarding safety & quality of the product. In addition, no matter who makes the product (a quick search on Amazon found similar products with U.S. plugs/120V, etc.) it is **critical** that the device be connected to an electrical outlet that is protected from **ground faults**. In the US that means "GFCI receptacle or GFCI breaker" and in other areas this may be RCD or another term.

**Any electrical device used in or near water where human contact is likely (and a faucet heater qualifies for that in every way) MUST have protection as a fault could be deadly.**